# What is the range of the predictor function in logistic regression?

Tags: regression, logistic

Is the predictor function in logistic regression a function of the dot product of the parameter vector and the feature vector onto a real value between zero and one?  If I'm getting dot products outside of that interval, does that mean my parameter vector is bad?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Logistic regression, the result of the linear predictor (g(x)) is from negative infinite to positive infinite.

[image]

Then the result of (pi(x)) ranges from 0 to 1 via the link function.
This is the definition.

Comment: Great, thanks!  For future readers, once you've done the dot product to get a number (which is really the Y coordinate in linear space... the answer to a linear regression problem in terms of log-odds) you transform it back into probability space by doing the following (where p is your answer):  exp(p) / (1 + exp(p) ) .  The resulting answer should be between 0 and 1.